# Como incluir comando if ao add um novo objeto em uma lista?

Tags: c#

Utilizo esse comando pra salvar uma nova `pessoa` uma lista:

```
class pessoa
{
    string nome;
    int idade;
    int sexo;
}

List<pessoa> pessoas.add(new pessoa()
{
    nome = "italo rodrigo",
    idade = 34,
    sexo = 1
});
```

Pra mostrar ao usuário, eu criei uma classe "temporária" só pro usuário ver na tela:

```
class pessoaT
{
    string nome;
    int idade;
    string sexo; //alterei de int para string
}
```

Quero fazer o seguinte: tenho uma lista de objetos `pessoa` e quero convertê-los em `pessoaT`

```
foreach (pessoa item in pessoa)
{
    List<pessoaT> pessoasT.add(new pessoaT()
    {
        nome = item.nome,
        idade = item.idade,
        if (item.sexo == 0)
            sexo = "F"
        else
            sexo = "M"
    });
}
```

O código acima dá erro no `if`. Como devo fazer pra funcionar corretamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a condição ternário

```
foreach (pessoa item in pessoa)
{
    List<pessoaT> pessoasT=new List<pessoaT>()
    pessoasT.add(new pessoaT()
    {
        nome = item.nome,
        idade = item.idade,
        sexo=item.sexo==0?"F":"M"
    });
}
```